how to download by pytube 15.0.0
from pytube import YouTube
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc"
url_full = "https://rr6---sn-w5nuxa-2its.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1735349663\\u0026ei=PwFvZ43zNYGU4t4PxsvXgAU\\u0026ip=2403%3A6200%3A88a0%3A4c34%3Acc5b%3A5f2a%3Af55a%3A828f\\u0026id=o-AOcwgX5a9MQ9_Vvl_6DKqICaXn4yK_HxsksaBiSD92aI\\u0026itag=18\\u0026source=youtube\\u0026requiressl=yes\\u0026xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D\\u0026met=1735328063%2C\\u0026mh=M9\\u0026mm=31%2C29\\u0026mn=sn-w5nuxa-2its%2Csn-w5nuxa-c33ls\\u0026ms=au%2Crdu\\u0026mv=m\\u0026mvi=6\\u0026pl=50\\u0026rms=au%2Cau\\u0026initcwndbps=3400000\\u0026bui=AfMhrI8b8omaOcjbHcOyWnV4m8qV_w8rl8NaLFWae492zkFTS-dZkGyUPBAWjMGO1U3MdAuXBY48rSec\\u0026spc=x-caUNFrVzAtl3o2_zcb2DplPkXcCaL_qnl0hKZx6UFvw_vcEEPAvXl5bShhPJKosKKN3aqHfQ\\u0026vprv=1\\u0026svpuc=1\\u0026mime=video%2Fmp4\\u0026ns=Qc-rpsF8IqJb2aIPOs227z0Q\\u0026rqh=1\\u0026gir=yes\\u0026clen=464495026\\u0026ratebypass=yes\\u0026dur=22446.915\\u0026lmt=1725846941052933\\u0026mt=1735327516\\u0026fvip=1\\u0026fexp=51326932%2C51335594%2C51355912%2C51371294\\u0026c=WEB\\u0026sefc=1\\u0026txp=4538434\\u0026n=n2DzpGGv2N9jEubDf\\u0026sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cbui%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cns%2Crqh%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt\\u0026sig=AJfQdSswRgIhALfvrnYr6ImCJWbieG8zKOXoUSxzV1cq8fdheiDhkEIMAiEAn6AyKk7ZgZg37JkkRaonLrpLKSljMZ7QA3mHWrg9yzo%3D\\u0026lsparams=met%2Cmh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Crms%2Cinitcwndbps\\u0026lsig=AGluJ3MwRQIgZ6itS1xC3Q-hXOLwnN4kQzlsgEGXoZgCcB2fisDfNn4CIQD8iRqoRTAraCstbl4fA5y3GtuU79MCGZAQ6GHjNMgE7g%3D%3D"
with urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read()

with open('html.txt','wb'):
    print(html)




start = YouTube(url_full)
start.streams.get_highest_resolution()

